# How to make a Google sheet template with a script where at each instance creation the user do not need to authorize the script access rights?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth

I have a google sheets with a menu a calling a script. The script is saved separately as Library with a saved version.
This Sheet is saved on a shared drive as Google domain template. The users create about 10 sheets a week and have each time to authorize the script.

Which solutions are available to avoid this recurring process. Add-on doesn't seem to be the right solution as the script has to work only for this Spreadsheet

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const rangeName="A2";
  var ass=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var as=ass.getActiveSheet();
  var adresse=as.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if (adresse===rangeName) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().rename(as.getRange(rangeName).getValue());
    ass.toast("DONE!");
  }
```

Comment: What does the script do?

Comment: I think your best option is deploying the script as an add-on. Could you share a copy of the script you're working on?

Comment: @cooper it renames automatically the spreadsheet with the contents of 3 different cells with a onEdit trigger

Comment: @lamblichus example script added

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your situation. What's the point of having an `onEdit` trigger used as a library that is called (if I understand you correctly) via a UI menu? How can this even work? Why can't you just have the `onEdit` in the script bound to your spreadsheet? The script wouldn't need authorization at all in this case (also, you could use the `onEdit` event object instead of the `getActive` methods.

Comment: @lamplichus: I only gave you an example as you asked. But for answering your question: the advantage of having I library is that you can Update the script in all your template instances without opening each data. 
But let us come back to the main topic. Ok assume I put in GSHEET Template and each time I create a Template instance I need to authorize. I do not want to authorise it each time. As I am changing the data Name I need to authorise.

Comment: I don't see how a library would be a better option, since when you want to update the library, you will have to create a new version, and the version number will have to be updated in each instance (if Development mode is not on). As I said before, I think the best way to avoid re-authorization is by publishing an add-on, even if you only want this to work for a single template.

Comment: @lamblichus that mean that I have permanently an addon installed for each of my templates? I have 25 differents templates. I need 25 add ons and  I have to manage then that an add on is not used on the wrong template

Comment: You could add some condition to the add-on code which only files created from the correct template will meet, like having a cell of a certain value, or what have you. And if the condition is not met, the add-on wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @lamblichus yes that could be a solution. But I have to install it manually for each user. Right?

Comment: If you're a domain admin, you can install the add-on for all users in the domain at once, without having to install it manually for each user. Check [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482). Also, if you think this solution suits your needs, I'll post an answer regarding this.

Comment: @lamblichus yes that would be nice. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have a script which should work for all copies made from a certain template (multiple users make copies).
- You want to avoid users having to re-authorize the script for each copy of the template they create.

If that's correct, I think your best option is to deploy the script as an add-on, and installing the add-on for all users in the domain. The workflow would be the following:

- Create a standalone Apps Script project and associate it with a [standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects).
- In the beginning of your function, look for a value in a certain cell, whose purpose is to identify the file as a copy of the template. For example, something like this:

```js
function yourFunction() {
  var templateIdentifier = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange("A1").getValue();
  if (templateIdentifier = "12345") { // Check that file is copy of template "12345"
    // Execute the desired script actions
  }
}
```

- The template and all its copies should have this value, so you should probably [protect this cell](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656) from edition in the original template (all copies will keep this protection). Personally, I'd also placing this cell in a hidden sheet so that users cannot see it.
- [Test](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons) that the add-on is working correctly, and [publish it](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/editor-publish-overview). following [this guide].
- Once the add-on is published, install it for all users in the domain, following [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482).

#### Reference:

- [Building editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons)
- [Install G Suite Marketplace apps in your domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482)

Comment: This is useful for all members in a domain, but what if the people using your template are not in your domain?